# how to display date format according to device time zone

Tags: android, datetime

I want to display date according to time zone... if its america than month date year and if its europe than date month year..it check the current date setting from device and convert current date and time according to time zone.
my code is

```
 Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        today.setToNow();

         String currentDateandTime = today.monthDay+"/"+today.month+"/"+today.year+"  "+today.hour+":"+today.minute;
```

can anybody suggest me some modification to have date organization according to time zone 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) class.

```
 DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG,Locale.FRANCE);
```

To get the users current [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) you can do

```
Locale.getDefault();
```

<strike>Be warned though it might not be what the user wants.</strike>

Comment: sorry but i didnt get what is mean by it might not be what user wants

Comment: the phones default locale might not be how the user expects the date to be represented

Comment: ok so what is your suggestion..i just want to display date according to area wether dd mm yyyy or america mm dd yyyy like this..what would you recommend me

Comment: You might as well use the default one, it will probably work fine for the majority of cases.